# Teoria sobre el sistema de rejillas css

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid-layout

Estoy viendo un vídeo sobre el sistema de rejillas en css, pero me surge una duda, a nivel de teoría. En estos momentos, el sistema de rejillas, por ejemplo el de Foundation ¿se utiliza para usarlo con Css grid y flexbox o ya no es necesario con los módulos que he indicado?

Gracias!

Answer (score 4):

una vez integres la librería puede ser Foundation o Bootstrap no necesitarás utilizar las reglas css grid ni flexbox simplemente le das las clases correspondientes a la documentación de dichas librerías para que funcione.

Por ejemplo en bootstrap si quieres realizar 4 columnas es algo así:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Contenido</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Contenido</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Contenido</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Contenido</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y solo con este HTML obtendrás 4 columnas de igual tamaño y responsive.

Espero te sirva mi respuesta.

Saludos!

Comment: Genial, me ha ayudado mucho. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Un gusto poder ayudarte! En caso de que la ayuda fue suficiente agradezco le des como resuelta a la pregunta, es un buen gesto!

Comment: La verdad que no se como se resuelve una pregunta, si me lo explicas, ahora mismo lo hago. Gracias.

Comment: @Raúl debajo de las flechas de votación, aparece un icono, presiona ese sobre la mejor respuesta. Es la mejor forma de agradecer a quien te responde en esta comunidad.

Comment: Gracias @EdgarGutiérrez será para la próxima :)

Answer (score 0):

hace poco me hice en SCSS un pequeño código para generar un sistema de rejillas de 12 columnas basados en flexbox, esto si no quieres depender de un framework.

HTML

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="flex-col-sm-12 flex-col-md-6 flex-col-lg-2"></div>
      <div class="flex-col-sm-12 flex-col-md-6 flex-col-lg-2"></div>
      <div class="flex-col-sm-12 flex-col-md-12 flex-col-lg-8"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
[class^='flex-col'] { width: 100%; }

$breakpoints: (
  xs: 540px,
  sm: 768px,
  md: 992px,
  lg: 1200px
);

.flex-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

@each $name, $value in $breakpoints {
  .flex-container {
    @media (min-width: $value) {
      max-width: $value;
    }
  }
  .flex-col-#{$name} {
    @for $i from 1 through 12 {
      &-#{$i} {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 1em;
        @media (min-width: $value) {
          width: calc(100% * (#{$i} / 12));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

.flex-row {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

https://codepen.io/neoxsaibot/pen/yraZEd

Si necesitas el CSS puedes ir a esta web https://www.sassmeister.com/ para convertir de sass a css.